# how to define a comment macro working in xcode on the mac

Tags: xcode, macos, macros, comments

it is quite useful to comment in/out lines using a macro for debug mode.

Unfortunately the normal approaches don't work on the Mac Xcode.

I tried `/ ## /` as well as using a two step macro like

```
#define COMMENT SLASH(/)
#define SLASH(s) /##s
```

which I also found in the web.

But neither works.

Do you have an idea which way to define a comment macro.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not this?

```
#ifdef DEBUG
// Do debug stuff here
NSAssert(...);
#endif
```

I am curious how / why you would use a comment macro.

Comment: I have to write a program in C (no Mac app, so no use of any MAC or iPhone lib nor objective C). So basically I use the XCode SDK to write this code. Since my files will be used by others I cant leave any includes for debug function or any call to debug functions in my code.    So the best is to just comment out all my debug efforts before I send my code off to the others. That's why I need to have a conditional comment macro. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: I see. But won't you still rely on some flag whether or not your comments should be enabled or not? Instead of #ifdef DEBUG you could say #ifdef MYDEBUG to have the same effect. Then before you ship your code put #define MYDEBUG

Comment: Yes, you are right. But the problem remains how to get the conditional comment. I dont mind to change the MYDEBUG definition in the my files - as long as I dont have to change anything else in my files.

Answer (score 1):

Same Problem here...

The answer seems to be that we expect a traditional while XCode uses a ISO-conform preprocessor (see http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/gcc-4.2.1/cpp/Traditional-macros.html#Traditional-macros)
There seems to be the possibility to change the options of the preprocessor, but who knows what you will break in the code from the apple SDKs.

I went through my code and changed my uses of such macros so that the macro is not followed by the code that should be hidden, but instead pass the code as parameter to the macro...
This way the code remains readable (not clobbered with #ifdefs)...
It only gets ugly if your debug-code contains ","